# How to check if an argument was given or not?

Tags: c++, argv, argc

```
//Checks if an argument was specified
if (argv[1] != "")
    strcpy(Buff1, argv[1]);
else
    strcpy(Buff1, "default");
```

If I run:
`./program test`

> Buff1 = test

If I run:
`./program`

> Buff1 = PACKAGES/=packages

How do I make it if nothing was specified, that Buff1 would be "default" by default?

Comment: That's why `argc` exists (sort of, since `argv` ends with a null string).

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include the solution. You invalidate the answers and that helps no one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `argc` to determine arguments count. It will be equal to 1 if no arguments were given, and 2 if one argument was given.

Note that you can't compare C strings using `==` operator. It's pointers comparasion.

Comment: Also worth noting the filename of the program itself is implicitly passed as `argv[0]`, which is why `argc` is 1 when no arguments are given.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, if nothing is passed, argc is going to be 1 (argc gives the number of passed arguments). This means that the only argv element with anything in it will be argv[0] (which contains the name of the program). That means a call to argv[1] will be an index out of range, possibly causing a crash, or if you're lucky will just be junk data.

```
if(argc == 1)
   strcpy(Buff1, "default");

else if(argc == 2)
    strcpy(Buff1, argv[1]);

else
    //do something here if there is more than 1 argument passed to it
```

It's also worthwhile to note that the way you passed the example arguments would not work with what you're intending: "./program test Buff1 = test" would result in argc being 4, with argv[0] being "test", argv[1] being "Buff1", argv[2] being "=" and argv[3] being "test".

Simply calling "./program test helllooo" would work with the program snipit I provided, filling Buff1 with "helllooo". And calling "./program test" would also work, filling Buff1 with "default". To do anything more advanced, you're going to have to get into command line switches (like ./program test -b somethinghere -x somethinghere), which is just a more advanced way of parsing argc and argv.

Answer (score 2):

The `argc` gives You the number of arguments passed to the program.
Keep in mind that `argc` can not be less than 1 since `argv[0]` is always program's name so if there were no arguments passed You should use this `if(argc == 1){}`

Answer (score 2):

Use `argc` for knowing how main arguments are passed. Shell or process invoker feeds the program with atleast one argument in general, that is program name itself and that is always the first argument. It turns out that `argc=1` atleast, and `argv[0]` is program name.

```
  int main(int argc, char **argv){
      // declarations and all here
      if(argc<2){
         strcpy(Buff1, "default");

        }
       else{
          strcpy(Buff1, argv[1]);
      }
     return 0;
  }
```

With out using this, you have two problems. When you use `argv[1]`, when `argc=1`, you are actually going array out of bounds. Since, `c++` doesn't do any bounds check for you, sometimes your program might fail silently accessing memory address next to the argv[0]. And another problem is that you are trying to compare the strings with `!=` operator. You can't compare string literals right away with `==`/`!=` operator. You have to use `strcmp` or an equivalent function.

Answer (score -1):

suggestion:
use argv.size() to get the count.

Comment: `argv` is a `char**`.  It has no member function.